# Generating demographic tables/frequencies of a large number of specific variables in R

Tags: r

I have larger data sets that for a 'first run' require basic frequencies by a group (groups are flagged with 1 or 0 in columns).  The issue is that some of the basic frequencies are for a very large number of variables (180 or so) that aren't named with a specific prefix and aren't positioned say in columns 2:100.  They could be in columns 2:80, and then say 90:117, etc.

I get the basic gist of doing this would be something like this:

```
mtcars %>% filter(gear == 4) %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% mutate(perc = n / sum(n)*100)
```

One issue is that my 3-5 groups are all flagged in separate columns, so I would need to use filter(pop1 == 1), filter(pop2 == 1), etc.  But is there a way for the group_by to go through 180 variables with an output for each variable?  It's just a simple frequency of each variable's values or missing.  So for the mtcars, it would be a frequency of just am, and then just vs.  It would be fine for the output to be one long one with two columns.

Like this:

```
Variable Value  n  Perc
am        0     4  33.3
am        1     8  66.7
vs        0     2  16.7
vs        1     10 83.3
```

I recognize this might involve gather or pivot_longer, but could not figure out a way to only transform the 180 variables out of say 200 that I need frequencies on to long.

**Edit:**

I ended up using this to select for many columns:

```
positions <- c(4:176,198)
```

And using select(positions) to circumvent typing in all of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` from `purrr` to separately do the grouping and apply the same code as in the OP's post

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(c('am', 'vs'), ~
      mtcars %>% 
        filter(gear == 4) %>% 
        group_by(Variable = .x, Value = !!rlang::sym(.x))  %>% 
        summarise(n = n()) %>% 
        mutate(perc = n/sum(n) * 100))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Variable [2]
#  Variable Value     n  perc
#  <chr>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 am           0     4  33.3
#2 am           1     8  66.7
#3 vs           0     2  16.7
#4 vs           1    10  83.3
```

---

Or another option is to convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
    filter(gear == 4) %>%
    select(vs, am) %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
    count(name, value) %>% 
    mutate(perc = n/sum(n) * 100)
```

Comment: Is there a way to select for all 180 variables without typing them out?  Such as saving the names?  If so, how would that go into the select step or map step?  Thanks

Comment: @PinkyL In my second ssolution, it is `filter`ing by the desired condition and `select` here only two variables.  If you want all the variables, then you can skip the `select` step and use `pivot_longer(everything())`