# Count causing Argument 'x' must be a vector: list

Tags: r

I posted a question previously, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883444/generating-demographic-tables-frequencies-of-a-large-number-of-specific-variable) and for some reason if I run the code now:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(gear == 4) %>%
  select(vs, am) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n) * 100)
```

It is now returning:

Error in count(., name, value) : Argument 'x' must be a vector: list

It was functional just a month ago, so I am baffled as to what is causing this.

Comment: You. may add `dplyr::count(name, values)` if you have already loaded `plyr` or any other package with the same function `count` also loaded

Comment: That helped!  Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably, it is a case of masking of the function with same function from a different package that got accidentally loaded.  If we use `::` to specify the package, it should work

```
mtcars %>% 
   dplyr::filter(gear == 4) %>%
   dplyr::select(vs, am) %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
   dplyr::count(name, value) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(perc = n/sum(n) * 100)
```

Here, we used the `::` in each of the function because `select/filter/mutate/count` are found in more than one package